# How to display the whole graph for BEMSimpleLineGraph？

Tags: objective-c, bemsimplelinegraph

I have nine x-axis labels whose names are: `4`, `5`, ..., and `12`, as seen in the picture below:

[image: BEMSimpleLineGraph]

However, the graph only shows eight labels (contains a half `4`). How can I display all x-axis labels on the graph on my screen?

My thought is reduce the distance between each label. But from the wiki, I did not find a related method.

**EDIT**
When I run the app on an iPhone with a smaller screen, there are fewer labels displayed.

Comment: are you using numberOfGapsBetweenLabelsOnLineGraph?

Comment: I did use `numberOfGapsBetweenLabelsOnLineGraph`, but it just reduce some labels, not display the whole graph